# Delete the checkbox values but when I click the button page refresh

Tags: php, database, checkbox, mysqli

Hey I write this code for delete the selected check box values from the database. Yeah I know there are some example already here. But when I take look on them and tried to do as per they done in their question. still doesn't get the success. Can you guys help me with this query. When I click on the on the delete button the page is refresh and message display that records are delete successfully but after that not see any records delete from database

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
        <meta name="" content="">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#05fa8c">
        <form action="a.php" method="POST">
            <table style="margin-top: 252px; font-size: larger; font-style: oblique;" align="center" bgcolor="#05fa8c">
                <?php
                    include("config.php");  // Connect to database

                        //$id = $_POST['id'];

                        $sbook = "SELECT * FROM `book`";
                        $rnq   = mysqli_query($con,$sbook);
                        $count = mysqli_num_rows($rnq);

                        if(!$rnq)
                        {
                            print ("Error: %s\n ". mysqli_error($con));
                        }

                        echo "<table border=2 table style=margin-top: 252px; font-size: larger; font-style: oblique; bgcolor=#05fa8c>
                        <tr>
                        <td width=10% height= 10%><b>Book Name:</b></td>
                        <td width=10% height= 10%><b>Author Name:</b></td>
                        <td width=10% height= 10%><b>Publisher Name:</b></td>
                        <td width=10% height= 10%><b>Description</b></td>
                        <td width=3% height= 3% align='center'><b>#</b></td>
                        </tr>";

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rnq))
                        {
                            $rid   = $row['id'];
                            $bname = $row['bname'];
                            $aname = $row['aname'];
                            $pname = $row['pname'];
                            $desc  = $row['description'];

                            echo "<tr>
                            <td width=10% height= 10%><b>$bname</b></td>
                            <td width=10% height= 10%><b>$aname</b></td>
                            <td width=10% height= 10%><b>$pname</b></td>
                            <td width=10% height= 10%><b>$desc</b></td>";?>
                            <td align='center'><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[<? echo $row['id']; ?>]" id="checkbox[<? echo $row['id']; ?>]" value="<? echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
                    <?php   } ?>
                    </table>
                        <input type='submit' name='delete' id='delete' value='Delete'>
                        <?php
                              foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $del_id){
                              $del_id = (int)$del_id;
                              $sql = 'DELETE FROM `book` WHERE `id` = '.$del_id;
                              mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                               echo "Records delete successfully";
                            }
                        ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `onClick='return false'` in your input

Comment: You cannot use fetched rows that way. $del_id = $row['id']; will get only (maybe) the last $row of select! Put the row data (from select) even inside another array and then change $del_id val

Comment: Try to debug it yourself.. in the for loop echo $del_id. Maybe that's empty. check if $count is empty.

Comment: your answer is in the commented part `foreach`, is this a trick question?

Comment: Nope not actually tricky question. In fact I use all this different way to get do the same thing but fails.. And i used you suggest Alex but not get the success. And still thinking that what you want to say@Marco Mura

Comment: Do you have mysqli extension installed?

Comment: $frantsium yes I have

Answer (score 0):

Move this block right after the connection to datebase line:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['delete'], $_POST['checkbox'])) {
        foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $del_id){
            $del_id = (int)$del_id;
            $sql = 'DELETE FROM `book` WHERE `id` = '.$del_id;
            mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            echo "Records delete successfully";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: okay i put the code right after the database connection and get the following error.  Notice: Undefined index: checkbox AND Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: i edited my answer, wrap your loop in if statement to check if the button delete was clicked

Comment: As you say but I tried already this and still stuck with this problem. I wrap the statement with if and when i click on the button page refresh and message "records delete "but didn't see any change in database

Comment: then check this query on errors as you did with the first one

Comment: you should definately use mysqli_error, and i also suspect that your user doesn't have privileges to delete data

Comment: I tried mysqli_error on every query and database connection. As this is admin panel so it doesn't used by any other user. Still stuck with the same problem which I faced

Comment: Answer is solved there are few silly mistake I did. Later on when I track the array by print_r than realize my mistake. Thank you all for your answers.